# How to use a firebase class in a js file

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a firebase file setup like so:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();
    this.storage = app.storage();
  }

  // *** Auth API ***

      doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
        this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

This is just part of the file.  To access it I setup a context

```
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
)
```

I then can wrap any component with `withFirebase` bada bing bada boom, it works.
However I'm trying out a redux type of library (react sweet state) which is pretty much a few js consts.  In example:

```
const initialState = {
  orgID: null,
  memberID: 'blah here',
  data: [],
}

const actions = {
  fetchOrg: () => async ({ setState }) => {
    const callFirebase = await Firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if(authUser) {
        //do some stuff
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  },
}
```

How can I use the firebase class instance in this setting?

I tried `const firebaseAuth = new Firebase();`
I get this error:  `Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).`

Comment: I am not sure about this but can you try `constructor() { if(!firebase.apps.length) {firebase.initializeApp(config)}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this ended up being just passing firebase as a prop to the action, which I believe is the "reacty" way of doing it:

```
const actions = {
  fetchOrg: firebase => async ({ setState }) => {
    const callFirebase = await Firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      if(authUser) {
        //do some stuff
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  },
}
```